# QTableWidget: different styles in *one* QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, coding-style, bold, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Is it possible to have a two-line element in a cell (QTableWidgetItem) of a QTableWidget with different styles per line? I want to have the first line **bold** and the second line not bold. Or can I add two QTableWidgetItems in one cell? Do a cellspan somehow?

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 2):

Simple way :

Checkout the [setCellWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.5/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget)  method of QTableWidget.

If you replace the default widget with [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtextedit.html), you can get rich text formatting capability.

Better way :

Use a custom QStyledItemDelegate. You can see an example [here](http://www.off-soft.net/en/develop/qt/qtb2.html?page=2)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hello OrcrunC! Thanks for the hint. I have tried this. It's working quite well but it takes quite a long time to load as there are many QTextEdit widgets now. I think it's an overkill as this widgets offers so many possibilities. Are there other options to display formatted text?