# QTableWidgetItem different font size in a single cell

Tags: c++, qt, qt4.8

is it possible to have, in `QTableWidgetItem` different font size in a single Cell.

I would have a cell with multi Line Text

```
twi = new QTableWidgetItem();
twi->setText("title \nAck \nTime");
```

giving something that would look like

title 
Ack 
Time

but what I want is

**title** 
Ack 
Time

is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6439286/2846711

Comment: thanks Yoann, I finnally had it working with the cellwidget

Answer (score 0):

Use `twi->setData(Qt::FontRole, QFont("", new_size));`.